# Get web page source, including javascript

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to create a Google Keyword Tool scraper with AutoIt.
I'm using the following code:

```
#include <IE.au3> 
$oIE = _IECreate ("https://adwords.google.com/o/KeywordTool")
sleep(20000)
$source = _IEDocReadHTML  ($oIE)

MsgBox(0,'',$source)
```

(The sleep is there to give me the time to type the query and click Search in the IE window - in the future I'll automate this)

The HTML source it outputs doesn't contain the table with the results, altough I can see it in Firebug.
Below there's a sigle row I've extracted with Firebug.

```
<tr __gwt_row="19" __gwt_subrow="0" class="sCT"><td class="sBS sDT sES" align="left"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1059"><div id="gwt-debug-column-SELECTION-row-19-0"><input type="checkbox" class="sML"></div></div></td><td class="sBS sDT" align="left"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1060"><div id="gwt-debug-column-KEYWORD-row-19-1"><span style="white-space:nowrap"><span></span><span><a class="sOL" gwtuirendered="gwt-uid-1089"><b>windows</b> live</a></span><span></span></span></div></div></td><td class="sBS sDT" align="left"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1062"><div id="gwt-debug-column-COMPETITION-row-19-2"><div title="0,04">Bassa</div></div></div></td><td class="sBS sDT" align="right"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1063"><div id="gwt-debug-column-GLOBAL_MONTHLY_SEARCHES-row-19-3">20.400.000</div></div></td><td class="sBS sDT" align="right"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1064"><div id="gwt-debug-column-AVERAGE_TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES-row-19-4">20.400.000</div></div></td><td class="sBS sDT" align="right"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1065"><div id="gwt-debug-column-SUGGESTED_BID-row-19-5">€&nbsp;0,40</div></div></td><td class="sBS sDT aw-ti-advertiser-specific-cell" align="right"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1066"><div id="gwt-debug-column-AD_SHARE-row-19-6">-</div></div></td><td class="sBS sDT" align="right"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1067"><div id="gwt-debug-column-AVERAGE_MONTHLY_SEARCHES_WITH_AFS-row-19-7">-</div></div></td><td class="sBS sDT aw-ti-advertiser-specific-cell" align="right"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1068"><div id="gwt-debug-column-SEARCH_SHARE-row-19-8">-</div></div></td><td class="sBS sDT" align="right"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1069"><div id="gwt-debug-column-TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES-row-19-9"><div style="width: 108px; white-space: nowrap" dir="ltr"><div style="width: 8px;height: 16px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 16px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 13px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 13px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 16px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 13px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 13px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 10px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 10px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 10px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 10px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div><div style="width: 1px;" class="goog-inline-block"></div><div style="width: 8px;height: 10px; background-color: #A4D0BB; vertical-align:bottom;" class="goog-inline-block" title=""></div></div></div></div></td><td class="sBS sDT sOS" align="left"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1070"><div id="gwt-debug-column-EXTRACTED_FROM_WEBPAGE-row-19-10">-</div></div></td></tr>
```

Is there a way to get the full source with Autoit, including the content generated with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I would use http request as it is the most direct way to do this.
It seems to give status 404 by the way
EDIT: The url was missing its last letter, causing the 404 status.

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <winapi.au3>


MsgBox(0,default,get_url("https://adwords.google.com/o/KeywordTool"))
  Func get_url($url)

    $RequestURL = $url;
    Global $oHTTP = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1") ;
    $oHTTP.Open("GET", $RequestURL, False)
    $oHTTP.Send()
    if  $oHTTP.status == 200 Then
        Return $oHTTP.ResponseText
    Else
         Return  "ooops... status: " & $oHTTP.status  
    EndIf

EndFunc
```